# How to turn the hotspot on automatically in Unity?

Tags: unity, mobile

I have made a simple LAN multi-player game in Unity (just for learning purposes).

This is the main code (for connection):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StartServer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform Makan;
    public Transform CubeOBJ;
    public string SSS; 

    void OnGUI () 
    {
        GUILayout.Box (Network.player.ipAddress);

        if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
        {
            SSS = GUILayout.TextField (SSS);

            if (GUILayout.Button ("StartServer"))
            {
                Network.InitializeServer(10, 25000);
            }

            if (GUILayout.Button ("Connect"))
            {
                Network.Connect (SSS, 25000);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button ("creatCube")) 
            {
                Network.Instantiate (CubeOBJ, Makan.transform.position, Makan.transform.rotation, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works good. The problem is that in mobile devices I should turn on hotspot by myself for one of the devices.

How can I do this automatically from code?

Comment: Why do you want to activate it automatically? Just alert the user that it is not active.

Comment: u mean there is no way to active it automatically?

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I said that what you want to do is not necessary.

Comment: maybe some users don't know how to turn on hotspot xD. anyway i want to know how to do it. and  why there is nothing about it in unity documentation?

Comment: Because it has nothing to do with Unity itself, it is about the device you run your game on.

Comment: @dave yeah now i undrestand :) the only way is to make plugin in java to do that (using android studio or..) for unity like this: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/57537